# pandas DataFrame .stack(dropna=False) but keeping existing combinations of levels

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My data looks like this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# My Data
enroll_year = np.arange(2010, 2015)
grad_year = enroll_year + 4
n_students = [[100, 100, 110, 110, np.nan]]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    n_students, 
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
        [enroll_year, grad_year], 
        names=['enroll_year', 'grad_year']))

print(df)
# enroll_year 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014
# grad_year   2014 2015 2016 2017 2018
# 0            100  100  110  110  NaN
```

What I am trying to do is to stack the data, one column/index level for year of enrollment, one for year of graduation and one for the numbers of students, which should look like

```
# enroll_year  grad_year    n
# 2010         2014         100.0
# .            .                .
# .            .                .
# .            .                .
# 2014         2018           NaN
```

The data produced by `.stack()` is very close, but the missing record(s) is dropped,

```
df1 = df.stack(['enroll_year', 'grad_year'])
df1.index = df1.index.droplevel(0)
print(df1)
# enroll_year  grad_year
# 2010         2014         100.0
# 2011         2015         100.0
# 2012         2016         110.0
# 2013         2017         110.0
# dtype: float64
```

So, `.stack(dropna=False)` is tried, but it will expand the index levels to all combinations of enrollment and graduation years

```
df2 = df.stack(['enroll_year', 'grad_year'], dropna=False)
df2.index = df2.index.droplevel(0)
print(df2)
# enroll_year  grad_year
# 2010         2014         100.0
#              2015           NaN
#              2016           NaN
#              2017           NaN
#              2018           NaN
# 2011         2014           NaN
#              2015         100.0
#              2016           NaN
#              2017           NaN
#              2018           NaN
# 2012         2014           NaN
#              2015           NaN
#              2016         110.0
#              2017           NaN
#              2018           NaN
# 2013         2014           NaN
#              2015           NaN
#              2016           NaN
#              2017         110.0
#              2018           NaN
# 2014         2014           NaN
#              2015           NaN
#              2016           NaN
#              2017           NaN
#              2018           NaN
# dtype: float64
```

And I need to subset `df2` to get my desired data set.

```
existing_combn = list(zip(
    df.columns.levels[0][df.columns.labels[0]], 
    df.columns.levels[1][df.columns.labels[1]]))

df3 = df2.loc[existing_combn]
print(df3)
# enroll_year  grad_year
# 2010         2014         100.0
# 2011         2015         100.0
# 2012         2016         110.0
# 2013         2017         110.0
# 2014         2018           NaN
# dtype: float64
```

Although it only adds a few more extra lines to my code, I wonder if there are any better and neater approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with `pd.DataFrame` then `reset_index` and `drop` unnecessary columns and `rename` the column as:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.unstack()).reset_index().drop('level_2',axis=1).rename(columns={0:'n'})

   enroll_year  grad_year      n
0         2010       2014  100.0
1         2011       2015  100.0
2         2012       2016  110.0
3         2013       2017  110.0
4         2014       2018    NaN
```

Or:

```
df.unstack().reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
enroll_year  grad_year
2010         2014         100.0
2011         2015         100.0
2012         2016         110.0
2013         2017         110.0
2014         2018           NaN
dtype: float64
```

Or:

```
df.unstack().reset_index(level=2, drop=True).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'n'})
   enroll_year  grad_year      n
0         2010       2014  100.0
1         2011       2015  100.0
2         2012       2016  110.0
3         2013       2017  110.0
4         2014       2018    NaN
```

---

**Explanation :**

```
print(pd.DataFrame(df.unstack()))
                             0
enroll_year grad_year         
2010        2014      0  100.0
2011        2015      0  100.0
2012        2016      0  110.0
2013        2017      0  110.0
2014        2018      0    NaN

print(pd.DataFrame(df.unstack()).reset_index().drop('level_2',axis=1))
   enroll_year  grad_year      0
0         2010       2014  100.0
1         2011       2015  100.0
2         2012       2016  110.0
3         2013       2017  110.0
4         2014       2018    NaN

print(pd.DataFrame(df.unstack()).reset_index().drop('level_2',axis=1).rename(columns={0:'n'}))
   enroll_year  grad_year      n
0         2010       2014  100.0
1         2011       2015  100.0
2         2012       2016  110.0
3         2013       2017  110.0
4         2014       2018    NaN
```